# Vlookup using a for-loop

Tags: python, vlookup

I have been trying to build `vlookup` function in python. I have two files. name = `data` - created in python which has more than 2000 rows. `comp_data` = csv file loaded in system which has 35 rows. I have to match date of data file with `comp_data` and have to load `Exp_date` corresponding to it. Current code gives error `35`. I am not able to understand the problem.

Following are the codes:

```
data['Exp_date'] = datetime.date(2020,3,30)
z=0
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data['Date'][i] == comp_data['Date'][z]:
        data['Exp_date'][i] = comp_data['Exp_date'][z]
    else:
        z=z+1
```

Comment: You're not iterating through comp_data, only data.  For each row in data you increment z by one, when you get to i=36, then z=36 which is larger than comp_data array, and it will error.

Comment: How should I go about it? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to put your comp_data in a dictionary with your data/exp_date as key/value pairs and let python do the lookup for you.

```
data = {"date":["a","b","c","d","e","f"],"exp_date":[0,0,0,0,0,0]}
comp = {"a":10,"d":13}

for i in range(len(data['date'])):
    if data['date'][i] in comp:
        data['exp_date'][i] = comp[data['date'][i]]
print(data)
```

There's probably a one-liner way of doing this with iterators!